# Bluemix Tradeoff Analytic,how to get the Visualization only without the widget

Tags: ibm-cloud, tradeoff-analytics

Hi Currently I'm doing some POC with Bluemix Tradeoff Analytics in use for mobile phone. and found out if we want to use the widget on the phone the view still not compatible on the phone i believe.

I wondering as for now I only interested with the Visualization to be shown in the phone without the entire widget to be loaded. is there any possibilities to do that?
[visualization image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VooeK.png)

any suggestion is appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to do it is to try to use CSS to remove the other parts from the display. They will still be loaded, but not shown.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes currently already play around with the CSS, as for now maybe that the only way. Thanks again